# Ember input de-focus clears model value

Tags: ember.js, input

I have an ember template with a text input and a `select` view bound to the same value.

```
{{input value=myValue}}
{{view "select" 
    content=myOptions 
    value=myValue 
    optionLabelPath="content.name" 
    optionValuePath="content.id"}}
```

I provide model data to back these options

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() { 
        return {
            myValue: 2,
            myOptions: [
                { name: 'a', id: 1 }, 
                { name: 'b', id: 2 },
                { name: 'c', id: 3 },
            ]
        }
    },
});
```

I've created a fiddle for it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f7Ldgv8a/1/).

The value initially displays fine. But if I focus the input box, and then either press an arrow key or de-focus it by clicking out of the input box, then the value disappears (the input box goes blank and the selection box shows no value selected).

This problem occurred in a much larger project, but the above code is what I've distilled the essence of it down to. It seems that removing the selection view makes the problem go away. I have searched but cannot find any material covering why this might be happening.

My question is: why am I seeing this behavior, and should I be doing this differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak to the why of this behavior at all. There are some discussions about Ember's select helper, specifically with the use of valueBinding vs selectionBinding, that are worth a look (as well as an open bug):

https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/82

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/482

That said, it seems to be a strange interaction with having both an input and a select binding to the same value. While this isn't your ideal answer (or mine), it is possible to work around it with some observers and using an intermediary thing to do the linking:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();
App.SomeType = Ember.Object.extend({
    myValue: null,
    myObj: null,
    objChanged: function() {
        var o = this.get('myObj');
        if(!o) {
            return;
        }
        this.set('myValue', o.id);
    }.observes('myObj'),
    valChanged: function() {
        this.set('myObj', this.get('myOptions')[this.get('myValue')-1]);
    }.observes('myValue'),
    myOptions: null,
});
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() { 
        var o = App.SomeType.create({
            myValue: 2,
            myOptions: [
                { name: 'a', id: 1 }, 
                { name: 'b', id: 2 },
                { name: 'c', id: 3 },
             ],
            });
            o.set('myObj', o.get('myOptions')[1]);
            return o;
        },
    }
);
```

HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    {{input valueBinding=myValue}}
    {{view "select" 
        contentBinding=myOptions 
        selectionBinding=myObj
        optionLabelPath="content.name"}}
</script>
```

I tried it in your fiddle and it seems to function properly. It just takes the direct binding of that value out of Ember's hands. It seems to have trouble with this kind of complicated/indirect binding.

Comment: So, you're saying that `selectionBinding` works better than `valueBinding` in this case? Is there a difference between `selection` and `selectionBinding`?

Comment: In general, go with xBinding if there is a chance that the thing may change from either side. That is, if the view might modify the value and you want to see it reflected in the model, or something might change the model and you want to see it in the view.

Comment: And yes, in this case I went with selection rather than value because I don't think the current implementation works very cleanly with optionValuePath. So here I preferred to bind to the view's selection as a whole object, and deal with putting the value in the right place myself.

Comment: So far my solution is to use `selectionBinding`, as you've suggested, and then use Ember Data's `belongsTo` to map the persistent ID to the model's property value (as opposed to managing it manually). This seems to be working so far. I'm going to accept your answer because so far it seems the best you can do if (A) you need to have the ID in the model instead of the object, and (B) you're not using Ember Data.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to share the solution I ended up with for anyone else who sees this question.

Firstly, I use Ember Data to define my model, and use fixtures to define the example values:

```
App.MyOption = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('name')
});

App.MyOption.FIXTURES = [
    { name: 'a', id: 1 }, 
    { name: 'b', id: 2 },
    { name: 'c', id: 3 },
];

App.MyModel = DS.Model.extend({
    myValue: DS.belongsTo('myOption')
});

App.MyModel.FIXTURES = [
    { 
        id: 1,
        myValue: 2
    }
];
```

In the model `myValue` is not a `DS.attr('number')`, but a `belongsTo`, which means that when Ember Data loads the fixtures (or presumably any server data), it will convert the `myValue: 2` into the actual object representing the value (`{ name: 'b', id: '2'}`). So Ember Data handles the mapping of IDs to objects, rather than exposing the ID to the template (which seems to have bugs in this regard).

Then when we load the model in the route, we use Ember Data to do this loading from the store (in this case our fixtures):

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() { 
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            myModel: this.store.find('myModel', 1),
            myOptions: this.store.find('myOption')
        });
    },
});
```

Now in the template, we bind to `myValue` as an *object* rather than an ID, using `selectionBinding` as recommended by Carl:

```
{{input value=myModel.myValue.name}}
{{view "select" 
    content=myOptions 
    selectionBinding=myModel.myValue 
    optionLabelPath="content.name"}}
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jzq1t8hj/) that shows the solution together.

Note: this solution has different behavior with respect to what it means to edit the text input. Previously it was a way to manually change which object is selected, while now it is a way to change the name of the currently selected object. In my particular case this is not a problem, but in yours this might be.